# Trocar de Banco de Dados de um sistema que está usando EF code first

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

Por favor, eu preciso mudar o BD de uma aplicação usando MySQL para passar a usar o MS SQL Server. Já migrei as tabelas, dados e relacionamentos.

O problema é que o sistema foi feito, eu acredito, no EF code first. O que tenho que fazer para trocar as chamadas? Os nomes de tabelas, chaves primárias e estrangeiras e tudo mais é igual.

Cheguei a alterar o seguinte código:

```
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

Esse trecho estou com dúvidas:

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">

  <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data"/>

  <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />-->
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx" />
  </providers>

</entityFramework>
```

O que preciso fazer para o EF entender que eu quero que ele aponte para o MS SQL Server? Tem receita de bolo para isso? Segue o arquivo completo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx" requirePermission="false"/>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>

    <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
       <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data"/>

       <providers>
          <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
          <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx" />
       </providers>
    </entityFramework>
<!--
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, MSSqlServer.Data"/>

    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>

  </entityFramework>
-->   
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionMysql" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost; user id=; Password=; SslMode=; database="/>
    <add name="ConnectionSqlServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="server=; user id=; Password=; database="/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
  </startup>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Não sei te responder isso, mas vou te dizer que, ao contrário da crença popular e do marketing da tecnologia, essa troca não fica boa, a não ser que repense boa parte do que fez ou se for coisas muito simples. Existem alguns casos que já estava tão ruim que nem sentirá problemas, e pode até em casos extremos melhorar porque tudo estava feito pra funcionar melhor de acordo com o SQL Server :D

Comment: #Maniero, obrigado por me dizer, mas infelizmente NÃO tenho escolha. A empresa quer padronizar TODOS os seus sistemas em uma única plataforma de armazenamento de dados.

Comment: Trocar não é o problema, a questão é que não é só trocar de DB e tudo fica lindo como se costuma vender

Comment: #Maniero, exatamente! Eu preciso de um passo-a-passo preciso para retirar o MySQL e colocar o MS SQL Server no mesmo código fonte C#. Se fosse ADO.Net puro seria até trabalhoso, mas não chegaria a ser difícil, o problema que EF Code NÃO mostra o que precisa ser feito.

Comment: Nunca fiz isso, mas, teoricamente, se o projeto não faz uso de nenhuma funcionalidade específica do SQL Server, é só trocar a connection string e o provider dentro do elemento `connectionStrings`, que você já fez. Faltou especificar na sua pergunta o que aconteceu depois que você fez essa troca, se deu algum erro ou não.

Comment: #Vítor Martins, se fosse ADO.Net PURO poderia até ser. Mas o "wizard" entity framework não é bem assim. Veja as cláusulas: "<providers>", "<defaultConnectionFactory", etc...

Comment: Mano, se a aplicação está code first, cria uma base de teste, muda a conexão pra essa base e executa o update-database para criar a estrutura para SQL-SERVER. COm tudo funcionando, depois terá de migrar os dados apenas.

Comment: #L. Jhon, "update-database"?!? Por favor cavalheiro, onde se encontra esse interessante comando?

Comment: Acho que encontrei algo... seria isso?

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cria uma nova aplicação usando sqlserver com uma tabela de teste e EF etc

só pra garantir que vc não está esquecendo de alguma referencia.

depois compare o web.config. adicione as referencias que vai usar.

preserve o nome da conexao. troque somente o banco

no video abaixo ele faz o update-database em 13:40

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZEvfQ0D8Mg

ps. tive que postar aqui pq o sistema nao deixa eu comentar

Comment: Legal Horácio Oliveira! Vou tentar.

Comment: <compilation debug="true" no webconfig pra ver os erros. se der algum vc atualiza ai pra gente ver

Comment: Putz... peguei o exemplo da DevMedia (Entity Framework Code-First Tutorial - DevMedia), mas está bem ruinzinho...

Comment: ESSE Tutorial está BEM melhor!  
Tutorial: Introdução ao Entity Framework 6 Code First usando MVC 5 (https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Arquivo de configuração -> 
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/config-file

Comment: Modelos e cadeias de caracteres de Conexão -> https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings

Comment: OUTRA COISA MUITO IMPORTANTE! Se você está trocando de BDs diferentes (no caso de MySQL para MS SQL server) precisa observar os TIPOS de dados. Exemplo: O Code First cria: VARCHAR(MAX)... mude para VARCHAR(UM TAMANHO CERTO QUE VOCÊ PRECISA). Não use, por exemplo:  "Interger(11,0)", use "Int". No caso do "TinyInt" use "Bit".